Cannot connect to MQ over SSL with .NET 8
I am using .NET 8 and the IBMMQDotnetClient 9.3.5.1 NuGet package. I am trying to connect to an IBM MQ queue running on a local Docker Linux container on my machine. My company has an Docker image that they have created for us to use for secure MQ development, and this is the image I am using.
However, I am unable to connect to the queue over SSL using a C# program.
I've tried several different things, but I continue to get a 2059 error back.
Here is the code for the method I am using to try to connect to the queue:
/// <summary>
/// Connects to the IBM MQ queue using the given parameters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="connectionType">One of the MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_values</param>
/// <param name="hostName">The host name for the queue</param>
/// <param name="channelName">The channel name for the queue</param>
/// <param name="queueManagerName">The queue manager name</param>
/// <param name="queueName">The queue name</param>
/// <param name="queueManager">Output parameter representing connection to MQ Queue Manager.</param>
/// <param name="isSsl">Flag indicating where to use SSL connection to queue.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="MQQueue"/> object representing the queue connection.</returns>
private static MQQueue GetConnectionToQueue(
    string connectionType,
    string hostName,
    string channelName,
    string queueManagerName,
    string queueName,
    out MQQueueManager queueManager,
    bool isSsl)
{
    var connectionProperties = new Hashtable
    {
        // Add the connection type
        { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, connectionType }
    };

    // Set up the rest of the connection properties, based on the
    // connection type requested
    switch (connectionType)
    {
        case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS:
            break;
        case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT:
        case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT:
        case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED:
            connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
            connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
            break;
    }

    // SSL stuff
    if (isSsl)
    {
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "*USER");
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
        // I also tried it with this CIPHER, but it doesn't work either
        //connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256");
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.MQCA_CERT_LABEL, "ibmwebspheremquf8472v");
        //connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
    }

    // Create a connection to the queue manager using the connection
    // properties just defined
    queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, connectionProperties);

    // Set up the options on the queue we want to open
    int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;

    // Now specify the queue that we want to open,and the open options
    var queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);

    return queue;
}

When I call this method, I am passing in MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED for the connectionType parameter.
I have the SSL certificate configured on a channel on the MQ instance running on the Docker Linux container and I can confirm that I can put a message on the queue over SSL using another program provided by my company. But I cannot connect to the queue over SSL with the C# code shown above.
I have also imported the certificate into my personal certificates, as shown below. I have turned on the logging, but I just get a lot of low level logging without much real help.
For example:
0000024C 16:49:17.457614   14024.1     Constructing IBM.WMQ.MQERD#005DDE0E MQMBID sn=p935-001-240405 su=_o1_M5vNNEe6mUKqTP0CEtw pn=basedotnet/nmqi/MQERD.cs
0000024D 16:49:17.458034   14024.1    -------------{  MQERD.ReadStruct(Byte [ ],int) inputs  [System.Byte[]] [28]
0000024E 16:49:17.458172   14024.1    -------------}  MQERD.ReadStruct(Byte [ ],int) rc=OK returns [8]
0000024F 16:49:17.459110   14024.1     New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2059

Any ideas on how to get the connection to work?


UPDATE

I have also tried connecting using the SimplePut program that comes with the IBM MQ client software installation just so I could rule out any problems with the code I wrote, and I get the exact same result. The location of the IBM program is C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base\SimplePut, and I compiled it using Visual Studio.
Result of running SimplePut IBM program using SSL channel:

Note that I can use this exact same SimplePut program over a non-SSL channel and it works fine as shown below, so that confirms that things like port, host name, queue manager name, etc are correct. So there is some sort of issue with the IBM MQ code not being able to find the certificate, or the certificate is not in the expected format, etc.
Result of running SimplePut IBM program using non-SSL channel:

One other pertinent thing I should mention is that the certificate file I imported into the Windows certificate store on my local machine is a p7b file (ibmwebspheremquf8472v.p7b). I am wondering if maybe the IBM MQ code cannot read that certificate, but I could not find anything on IBM's docs on that.
And after re-checking the AMQERR01.LOG file on the Linux container, it's not finding the certificate, but this seems to be on the server side.


What does the queue manger's AMQERR01.LOG show you when you get the 2059?

I don't see any indication that your problem is related to TLS. MQ Reason 2059 usually indicates a problem with the availability of the Queue Manager on the specified target address.  You have not specified MQC.PORT_PROPERTY (int) in your code. Are you sure the port your container exposes for the MQ Listener can be accessed from outside the container on port 1414 or is it mapped to any other port? If it is on any other port, you need to set this property.

@JoshMc - There is nothing in the AMQERR01.LOG file regarding the 2059 error.  I'm looking at the file in /var/mqm/errors on the Linux container. If that's not the right place, please let me know.

@Nine Friends - Port is 1414..  https://imgur.com/RrGrPT4

The screenshot shows that the MQ listener listens on port 1414. That will also be the port which is exposed by the container. But this is not necessarily the port on which this service can be accessed from outside the container. For example with docker it would be the mapping you added with the -p parameter of "docker run" command.

The docker command is: docker run -p 6414:1414 -v mqdockeropt:/opt --name gim-test-sqm-container bc211aebc8df /usr/bin/startmq.sh.  I tried setting the port directly in the connectionProperties (see C# code above) and I tried both 6414 and 1414 but both failed with the error noted above.

Whatever further change is required to solve your problem, it is port 6414 you have to address from outside the container, not 1414.

I think the port is ok because I am able to put a message on the queue when not using SSL.  My understanding is that for the IBMMQDotnetClient NuGet package, you have to put the certificate in the windows store (see the screenshot in my question). I think for some reason, the MQ code is not getting that certificate.

@Nine Friends - You can refer to my latest update in the question, I'm able to reproduce the problem with the sample code provided by IBM.

Your recent update is very valuable. You are right, the local certificate is not picked up. p7b is supported (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=client-key-repositories-managed-net). If you have installed it on local computer account you have to set parameter -k to *SYSTEM. You would set it to *USER if you have installed the certificate for the user account. Based on your description "I imported into the Windows certificate store on my local machine" you may give it a try with "-k *SYSTEM".

@Nine Friends - Thanks for the comment, but sadly, I get the same result with *SYSTEM.

Same result means the same mq reason code 2059 or the same error in AMQERR01.LOG? On which account have you installed the certificate - computer account or specific user. If it is for a specific user, is it the user who runs the application?

Yes, cert was for user that was running application.  Anyway, at this point we have switched over to the native C libs (unmanaged calls) since that seems to be much easier to get working and you don't have to mess with the Windows certificate store.  Thanks so much for your help though.
